# Tif to PDF conversion Inverse problem

Tags: pdf, tiff

I'm using irfanview to convert a batch of .TIF images into .PDFs, all the TIF's are white background with black text and lines.

However when using advanced batch mode a small percentage of these have been inversed in the process of creating the PDF, and I'm not sure why.

Here's the irfanview command.

```
i_view32 c:\extract\tifs_extract\* /advancedbatch /convert=c:\extract\pdfs\*.pdf
```

I think it's something more likely to do with the TIF file than an issue in the command above, as that generates 95% of them fine.

The images look fine as .TIF's. Has anyone ever come across something similar and if so how did you fix it.

Comment: You can check the TIFF Tags to see if there is any noticible differences.  A tool for viewing TIFF tags: http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/astifftagviewer.html  Documentation of the TIFF tags: http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/baseline.html

Answer (score 1):

Check if the TIFF file contains a tag called [Predictor (0x013D)](http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/predictor.html). You may find this flag in grayscale or color (continuous-tone) TIFF images with LZW, ZIP or PACKBITS compression.

This flag is used by some imaging software to improve the compression ratio of continuous-tone TIFF images. However, this flag is incompatible with the PDF specification for embedding images, therefore such images will need to be re-compressed without this flag prior to embedding with PDF.

Answer (score 1):

TIFF is a  funny format in that there are quite a few different ways to encode any particular image that are supposed to generate equivalent pixels.  For 1 bit images, you're supposed to set a tag that indicates whether a 0 bit is black or a 0 bit is white, but the image might also be encoded with a color table that explicitly says what the color is supposed to be.  A TIFF renderer could easily get this wrong (or generate incorrect PDF) for it.

Answer (score 0):

Some PDF images have a Decode Array which inverts the image and not all PDF tools support. Does it work with other tools?

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be due to the colorspace of the images. Some of the components have issues in detecting the CMYK images. Ensure that all your images are in RGB color mode rather than CMYK to get a perfect output.