# Invert a binary TIFF file without recompressing it

Tags: image, pdf, tiff

When converting black and white images from TIFF to PDF (image embedded in page) or back, the image's colors may get inverted: [Tif to PDF conversion Inverse problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820558/tif-to-pdf-conversion-inverse-problem) https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2011/08/ccitt-encoding-in-pdf-files-black-and-white-facts/

So, given a binary TIFF file, I'd like to invert its colors, **but without re-encoding or re-compressing the data**. It is possible to do so by editing the metadata only and I'd like to know how.

Any open source tool, library or programming language is okay for me. From what I've gathered so far, there are multiple steps in the decoding pipeline that may achieve the desired result (add some flag, flip the color palette, etc.).

Comment: You could try the 2 tools suggested here and change MINISBLACK to its inverse and see what happens... https://stackoverflow.com/a/73461777/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thank you very much, the link pointed me to tiffset, whose man page even provides an example to configure that exact option. `tiffset -s 262 0` resolves it for me. Feel free to create an answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the 2 tools suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73461777/2836621) and change `MINISBLACK` to its inverse and see what happens...

As you say in your comment, the following seems to do as you asked:

```
tiffset -s 262 0 YOURIMAGE.TIF
```